# How I can cast an uint8 to a struct representing a byte?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct representing a byte having a fix offset 0b1111. I have defined a conversion operator to cast the SByte to unit8.

1. How can I have the opposite conversion (from uint8 to SByte)?
2. Is the only solution to replace the SByte with a **uint8_t** or maybe a **union** in the first place?

```cpp
struct SByte
{
  uint8_t offset : 4;
  uint8_t bit4 : 1;
  uint8_t bit5 : 1;
  uint8_t bit6 : 1;
  uint8_t bit7 : 1;

  SByte():offset(15), bit4(0), bit5(0), bit6(0), bit7(0){}
  explicit operator int8_t() const
  {
    return static_cast<uint8_t>((bit7 << 7) | (bit6 << 6) | (bit5 << 5) | (bit4 << 4));
  }
};
int main()
{
  auto lbyte = SByte();
  auto result = static_cast<int8_t>(lbyte);
  assert(result == 15); // 0b00001111
}
```

Comment: Create a constructor that receive an `uint8_t` and build a `SByte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I have the opposite conversion (from uint8 to SByte)?

By defining a constructor:

```
explicit SByte(uint8_t byte) {
    // extract individual bits from `byte`
}
```

Comment: The power of the _XY problem_ is amazing. Thanks